# text check point with RTE protocol recording in loadrunner

Tags: loadrunner

I am recording application with RTE protocol. I need to put text check point with function "TE_find_text" for below highlighted text. i am trying with function 'Te_text_find("FG Txn in traceREADY")',but is is asking arguments. Please suggest how to add arguments.

[Original GUI image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGxww.png)

[RTE (TELNET) protocol recording image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEspS.png)

Comment: Is the application in question using a terminal protocol under the covers of the GUI which you have shown?

Comment: Yes sir ,need to keep text check point for the text "FG Txn in traceREADY" in terminal protocol as per the above image

Comment: You show me a GUI, not a terminal window as I would expect with RTE, and tell me you are using a terminal protocol.  Very confusing

Comment: I am using RTE (TELNET) protocol to record above GUI appliaction. need to keep text check point Te_text_find("FG Txn in traceREADY")',. please see the one more attachment for more details.